# No module named discord.ui

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im running a script for a bot with the website Replit and when I see people add select or buttons to their script it works. For some reason mine doesnt work, when I run it gives me the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ui'. I dont know if its because of my version or maybe the website. This is the code:

```
import discord, os, requests, json, random, time
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
import urllib
from discord.ui import Select
```

When I see youtube tutorials on this it works perfectly and when I read the comments there was no trouble, so I dont know why mine doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: try pip install discord-ui

Comment: First, you shouldn't follow YouTube tutorials. Second, the `ui` module was added in discord.py V2.0, so are you sure that the discord.py you've installed is version `>= 2.0`?

Comment: I dont think I have yet

Comment: the pip install discord-ui didnt work, also how do I change my version to 2.0?